# Navigate to createStackNavigator page from createBottomTabNavigator not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

**In my project I have one Login page which is in stacknavigator and 2 pages which are in createBottomTabNavigator. createBottomTabNavigator is included inside stack navigator. I want to go back in Login page from any of the pages which are in createBottomTabNavigator. For navigation I am using "react-navigation": "^3.12.0"**

> Code of navigation stack:-

```
    const RootStack = createStackNavigator({

          Login:{
            screen:LoginScreen
          },
          Home:{
            screen:HometabNavigator
          },
    }, {
        initialRouteName: 'Login',
        headerMode: 'none'
    });
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

> Code in screen:HometabNavigator:-

```
const TabStack = createBottomTabNavigator({

    Dashboard: {
        screen: Dashboard,
        navigationOptions: () => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Image
                    style={{
                        resizeMode: 'contain',
                        width: 18,
                        height: 18,
                        alignSelf: 'center',
                        marginLeft: 12,
                        marginRight: 12,
                        tintColor: tintColor
                    }}
                    source={IMAGEPATH.DASHBOARD_ICON_IMAGE}
                />
            )
        })
    },
    CoursePlan: {
        screen: CoursePlan,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Image
                    style={{
                        resizeMode: 'contain',
                        width: 18,
                        height: 18,
                        alignSelf: 'center',
                        marginLeft: 12,
                        marginRight: 12,
                        tintColor: tintColor
                    }}
                    source={IMAGEPATH.COURSE_ICON_IMAGE}
                />
            )
        })
    }
});

let TabNavigation = createAppContainer(TabStack);

class HometabNavigator extends React.Component {
        <TabNavigation />
}
export default HometabNavigator;
```

Now I am trying to navigate from CoursePlan to Login and the code is below:-

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
```

But the page is not navigating to login. What wrong I am doing here?

Thanks is advance

Comment: you forgot to export TabNavigation!!

Comment: @bk7 Actually I have exported it. I did not included that. I am updating the code. Please review the code.

Comment: This link is very helpful, I have to navigate without navigation props:- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/3.x/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation configuration is wrong. The container cannot be wrapped back into the container

You need to modify the navigation configuration.

- createAppContainer

  - createStackNavigator

    - Login
    - TabStack(createBottomTabNavigator)

```js
   const RootStack = createStackNavigator({

          Login:{
            screen:LoginScreen
          },
          Home:{
            screen:TabStack
          },
    }, {
        initialRouteName: 'Login',
        headerMode: 'none'
    });
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

Comment: I dont understand this, can you please give me a code snippet ?